# Vite 4.2.0 is loading commonjs code, when ES6 is available and type = module, in sveltekit project

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I am getting this stack trace from my sveltekit app:

```
Internal server error: require() of ES Module /Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/model/string/ui/package/index.js from /Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/model/assembled/dist/cjs/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/model/string/ui/package/index.js in /Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/model/assembled/dist/cjs/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/model/assembled/dist/cjs/index.js:4:27)
      at async Promise.all (index 0)
      at async nodeImport (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.2.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:54039:21)
      at async eval (/src/lib/MainPanel.svelte:10:31)
      at async instantiateModule (file:///Users/mikehogan/repos/personal/cozemble/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.2.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-79892de8.js:53996:9)
```

The sveltekit app has this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@cozemble/frontend-main-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
    "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
    "test": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --threshold error"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs": "^1.0.3",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "svelte": "^3.54.0",
    "svelte-check": "^3.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cozemble/backend-tenanted-api-types": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/data-editor-sdk": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/data-paginated-editor": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/lang-util": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-api": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-assembled": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-core": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-editor": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-event-sourced": "workspace:*",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "daisyui": "^2.47.0"
  }
}
```

It includes `@cozemble/model-assembled`.  The package.json for that is:

```
{
  "name": "@cozemble/model-assembled",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc -p tsconfig.json && npx tsc -p tsconfig-cjs.json",
    "test": "echo NA"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cozemble/lang-util": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-core": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-string-core": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-string-ui": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-reference-core": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-reference-ui": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-attachment-core": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-attachment-ui": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

The package.json for `@cozemble/model-string-ui` is:

```
{
  "name": "@cozemble/model-string-ui",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "svelte": "./package/index.js",
  "module": "./package/index.js",
  "main": "./package/index.js",
  "types": "./package/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-package",
    "prepublishOnly": "echo 'Did you mean to publish `./package/`, instead of `./`?' && exit 1",
    "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
    "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
    "test": "svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --threshold error"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/package": "^1.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.54.0",
    "svelte-check": "^2.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cozemble/model-core": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-api": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-string-core": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/model-editor-sdk": "workspace:*",
    "@cozemble/data-editor-sdk": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

So my sveltekit app (type: module) loads `@cozemble/model-assembled` (which supports commonjs and es6 package format) which in turn loads `@cozemble/model-string-ui` (type: module).  Why is the commonjs package of `@cozemble/model-assembled` chosen over the es6 version?

Version information:

@sveltejs/kit: 1.14.0
vite: 4.2.1

Update #1: The issue seems to be that when I deleted my pnpm-lock.yaml file earlier in the day, vite changed from version 4.1.4 to 4.2.1, and that introduced the issue.  Also happens using 4.2.0. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: When are you getting this error? I could build the project successfully and when I run main app I get a different error: `Error: Not found: /configurer
    at resolve (/@fs/C:/Yazılım/Clients/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@1.14.0_svelte@3.57.0+vite@4.2.1/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:291:18)
  ...`

Comment: When I try to login and it redirects to the tenant specific url